# Rails how to know if a has_one/belongs_to relationship exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, belongs-to, has-one

I have a 'User' (devise), and a 'Location'.  A user `has_one` location while a location `belongs_to` user. I have an instance variable in my controller that only should exist if two conditions are true.

```
if user_signed_in? && !current_user.location.empty?
```

But the error returns:

```
undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

Which is right because the `current_user` doesn't have a location.  I'm searching on Google about this for 2 hours.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's giving you the undefined method error because `current_user.location` is not an array. `empty?` can only be used on an array. Try using `nil?` instead.